# Google App-Engine memcached extremely slow

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, memcached, latency

I recently launched my app for iPhone/Android running with AppEngine backend. This is my first experience using AppEngine in Production.

As I get more traffic, I am starting to experience serious latency issues. Currently minimum idle instance is 1, max_pending_latency is 1s.

Yes, there are rooms for optimizations on my side, however I do not understand

1. Why the latency is not correlated with request/sec, traffic, memoryUsage, memcacheUsage, anything. I do not understand why there was no significant latency on Sep 21.
2. Why the call to memcached needs to be as slow as 500ms. (Usually it is 10 times faster). I am using NDB and 1GB dedicated memcached. Increasing to 5GB had no effect.

Is this simply how AppEngine works? I would like to get your insight.

Thanks

[image: Latency] [image: Requests per second] [image: Example RPC]

Comment: You may want to ask this in the #appengine channel on freenode or the mailing list. Your rpc chart shows a synchronous set of ndb transactions but the memcache part shouldn't take so long.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it's possible to see times like that in Memcache. Performance times aren't guaranteed unless using dedicated (paid) Memcache. [source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/#Python_Limits)

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston Thanks for suggesting a good contact point. As you pointed out, the synchronous calls should be either parallelized or sent to task-queue.

Comment: @Nick I am using a dedicated Memcache already. Sounds like there is something going wrong then.

Comment: Are you making 2 datastore reads then 2 datastore writes and 2 other datastore reads in the same request?

Comment: @janscas That is correct. I am thinking of moving more ops to TaskQueue.

Comment: Just try to group rpc ops with getmulti or putmulti

Comment: Grouping RPC calls is a good idea for performance. I also need to clarify that dedicated memcache actually only has a guarantee on storage space. Volatility, latency are not spoken of as far as I can see in the documentation. [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/developers-console/#memcache) [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/features/#memcache)

Comment: What is the size of data you are using with the requests that are taking 300+ms or 500+ms? How big are the requests that take much less time: are they much smaller or about the same?

Comment: @DaigoSato — any updates? Also, has the performance always been the same, or has it degraded over time? I'd like to understand what you're seeing so that we can get to the bottom of this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to update this.... I remember the issue was caused by me creating datastore keys by myself. Basically, not well distributed keys introduced "hot tablet" problem. Once I stopped creating my own keys and let the AppEngine create them, the issue seemed to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

We experienced a very long time in deserialization when we stored a lot of entities under the same memcache key. It can take a long time if you store a big array of some entities with a lot of structured properties.

You cannot store object size more than 1Mo in the same cache key. You can use [Titan for App Engine](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/titan/) to divide your cache key in several others cache key using the [sharded memcache](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/titan/blob/master/titan/common/sharded_cache.py). It's transparent.

I hope it will help you.